# Using alternate scm provider in maven-scm-publish-plugin

Tags: java, maven, svn, maven-scm-plugin

I want to update local project from remote SVN with Maven (without to have SVN command installed)
I`m trying to use alternate scm provider in maven-scm-publish-plugin following the example plugin config looks like:

```
   <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-scm-publish-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <providerImplementations>
              <svn>javasvn</svn>
            </providerImplementations>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
              <version>2.0.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
              <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
              <version>1.7.11</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

source: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-scm-publish-plugin/various-tips.html

But after execute `mvn scm:update` it`s have in Maven log

> [INFO] --- maven-scm-plugin:1.9.5:update (default-cli) @ testscm ---
>
> [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/stanimir/ProjectSvnTest && svn --non-interactive update /home/stanimir/ProjectSvnTest

and error: `svn not found` - I know.. it is not installed on system. I want to use svnkit instead but how this plugin to use javasvn?

Comment: Why are you trying to configure maven-scm-publish-plugin ? Why are trying to download a repository from SVN ? Are you talking about a Maven repository which is committed into SVN ?

Comment: This pom.xml is committed to existing SVN repository. My goal is to update the project using `mvn scm:update`

Comment: What about simply using `svn upd`? Why so compilcated via Maven?

Comment: The problem is that there is only Maven on the system installed and `svn update` will fail with the same error `svn not found` there is not svn cli installed on the server and I cannot change this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run the wrong Maven plugin from command line `mvn scm:update` (without configuration) instead of `mvn scm-publish:update`
Finally I have success with maven-scm-plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <providerImplementations>
                        <svn>javasvn</svn>
                    </providerImplementations>
                    <connectionUrl>scm:svn:https://..</connectionUrl>
                    <username>user</username>
                    <password>XXX</password>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.11</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

To clone SVN repository: `mvn -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false scm:checkout`

To update it: `mvn scm:update`

> [INFO] --- maven-scm-plugin:1.9.5:checkout (default-cli) @ testscm ---
>
> [INFO] Change the default 'svn' provider implementation to 'javasvn'.